# Need to Run Bash commands in groovy Jenkins script

Tags: bash, shell, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

While running this Bash command in an `sh """` block I am getting an error in the below Groovy Jenkins code.

I am getting this error:

```
/home/jenkins/workspace/_api-build_features_SSSVCS-12870@tmp/durable-be642e71/script.sh: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string
```

for the below 2 lines of Groovy code:

```
aa = sh(script: "aa=\"\$(helm2 version --short --client|awk '{print substr(\$2,1,2)}'\"; echo \$aa", returnStdout: true).trim()
```

I am using the variable aa in below if then else loop, Please suggest me.

```
sh """
       if [ aa == v2 ]; then
        helm package --save=false ${extraArgs} ${PROJ}
       else
        helm package ${PROJ}
       fi
sh """
```

Comment: `if` is not a loop, it's a flow-control statement.

Answer (score 1):

In the first line, you miss a closing the bracket ')'. In the second block, consider removing  the second sh, otherwise will be part of the whole string between the two """.

Comment: `aa` is just a static string there, not a variable.

Comment: The syntax error is not in the groovy, it is on the Bash side. `$(expression)` is not well terminated.

Comment: You are repeating information which is already in the answer, but this is not sufficient to fix the OP's problem. I'm trying to point out another problem which will also need to be fixed, though I can't say where or how exactly to address that. `if [ aa == v2 ]` can never be true because the strings `aa` and `v2` are not equal. (Also, `==` should be `=` in proper POSIX `sh`.)

Comment: Is it Correct. ?  
i have tried to implement your comments into my code.

aa = sh(script: "aa=\"\$(helm2 version --short --client | awk '{print substr(\$2,1,2)}'\"); echo \$aa", returnStdout: true).trim()

Comment: Now it looks okay, but you must verify it.